Cut an imperial half sheet into 4:3 sheets
Suppose you have a watercolour paper sheet measuring 56 cm by 38 cm.
You want to cut it into smaller sheets, knowing that:

all sheets must have proportions 4:3, chosen among the following 3 sizes: 30 x 22.5, 20 x 15, 15 x 11.25 (more than one size can be chosen)
leftovers/scrap pieces are allowed, but you should have minimal waste

I see some posts related to '2D packing' and similar, but some of the links seems to be broken.
Would you be able to point me to methods to resolve this?
I guess some form of linear programming may work, given the constrained optimisation nature of the problem, but I am not sure how I would encode the geometric aspect without biasing the solution or knowing the tiling/arrangement upfront.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
EDIT showing a graphical approach
Following up from the suggested solution by @Ethan Bolker:

The light grey rectangle is the starting sheet.
The yellow-green sheets are the smallest ones (15 x 11.25).
$2 * 5 * 15 * 11.25 = 1687.5$
$56 * 38 = 2128$
EDIT 2 more 'trial-and-error' graphical solutions




EDIT 3 stub of a possible linear programming solution
Showing below what I could come up with so far.
I found these two links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem
https://github.com/ktnr/BinPacking2D
Perhaps the github example could be used in practice.
Here is my take.
We want to fill the initial 56 x 38 rectangle with a combination of non-overlapping rectangular tiles of sizes A: 30 x 22.5, B: 20 x 15, C: 15 x 11.25.
As the orientation can be vertical, too, there are in fact 3 additional tiles we can use: A': 22.5 x 30, B': 15 x 20, C': 11.25 x 15.
The optimal solution is the one where the maximal fraction of the initial area $56 * 38 = 2128$ is covered, without of course exceeding it.
A solution can have $1, 2, ..., n$ tiles in it. Given that the smallest tile has an area $15 * 11.25 = 168.75$, a safe upper bound for $n$ is $2204 / 168.75$ rounded to the floor, i.e. 13.
One can then enumerate and study sets of solutions with each possible number of tiles.
A solution with 1 tile can contain any of the 6 tiles $[[A], [B], [C], [A'], [B'], [C']]$.
The location of the tile can be expressed as coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ of its bottom-left corner, taking $(0,0)$ as the bottom-left corner of the initial sheet. If the tile has size $(s_x, s_y)$ This implies that $x_1 \ge 0, y_1 \ge 0, x_1 + s_x \le 56, y_1 + s_y \le 38$.
So far this is fairly easy to solve, and in fact infinite valid solutions exist, using either A or A' located in any allowed place within the initial sheet.
A solution with 2 tiles can contain any combination, i.e. the cartesian product of $[[A], [B], [C], [A'], [B'], [C']]$ by itself (i.e. $[[A, A], [A, B], [A, C], [A, A'], ..., [C', B'], [C', C']]$), excluding the ones where the sum of the tile areas exceeds $2204$ (in this case non of the 36 combinations is excluded).
Here one also needs to impose non-overlapping constraints. And that's where I am struggling/guessing a little bit.
Given the bottom-left corner of tile 1 $(x_1,y_1)$, of size $(s_{x1},s_{y1})$, and the bottom-left corner of tile 2 $(x_2,y_2)$, of size $(s_{x2},s_{y2})$, how can I write constraints such that the two tiles do not overlap?
Given that the combinations include the order of the tiles (i.e. $[A, A']$ and $[A', A]$ are considered different), I can assume that the bottom-left corner of tile 1 'dominates' the bottom-left corner of tile 2, in a Pareto sense. That would mean $(x_1 \le x_2) \lor (y_1 \le y_2)$. But that is not sufficient. To avoid overlapping, I should impose $(x_1 + s_{x1} \le x_2) \lor (y_1 + s_{y1} \le y_2)$.
Then I would need to find back that article that explained how to encode logical constraints in linear programming...
But I am just guessing here. Any advice?
EDIT 4 how to know if any tiles are overlapping
Found a couple of links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549544/total-area-of-intersecting-rectangles
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/total-area-two-overlapping-rectangles/
So, for each pair of tiles 1 and 2, there is no overlap if:
$\max(x_1, x_2) >= \min(x_1 + s_{x1}, x_2 + s_{x2}) \lor \max(y_1, y_2) >= \min(y_1 + s_{y1}, y_2 + s_{y2})$
How to translate that to linear programming constraints, is (I suppose) what I'd need to figure out to progress with this.
EDIT 5 solution using python + ORtools as per RobPratt's suggestion
Conversion to integers and rounding of the total sheet size as per Jaap's suggestion.
python code:
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#---------------------------------------------------
# data
#---------------------------------------------------

data = '''
item         width    height available    value    color
L               24        18         2      432     blue
M               16        12         3      192   orange
S               12         9         6      108    green
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')
print("Input data")
print(df)

H = 30
W = 44

print(f"\nContainer width:{W} height:{H}")

#---------------------------------------------------
# derived data
# expand to individual items
#---------------------------------------------------

w0 = df['width'].to_numpy()
h0 = df['height'].to_numpy()
a0 = df['available'].to_numpy()
v0 = df['value'].to_numpy()
indx0 = np.arange(np.size(w0))

w = np.repeat(w0,a0)
h = np.repeat(h0,a0)
v = np.repeat(v0,a0)
indx = np.repeat(indx0,a0)

n = len(w)
print(f"Number of individual items: {n}")

#---------------------------------------------------
# create rotated items
# by duplicating
#---------------------------------------------------

wr = np.concatenate((w,h))
hr = np.concatenate((h,w))
vr = np.concatenate((v,v))
vr = (vr*1000.0).astype('int')  # scale values to become integers
indxr = np.concatenate((indx,indx))

nr = 2*n
print(f"Number of individual items (after adding rotations): {nr}")

#---------------------------------------------------
# or-tools model
#---------------------------------------------------

model = cp_model.CpModel()

#
# variables
#

# u[i] : item i is used
u = [ model.NewBoolVar(f"u{i}") for i in range(nr) ]

# x[i],y[i] : location of item i
x = [ model.NewIntVar(0,W,f"x{i}") for i in range(nr) ]
y = [ model.NewIntVar(0,H,f"y{i}") for i in range(nr) ]

# xw[i],yh[i] : width/height item i
xw = [ model.NewIntVar(0,int(wr[i]),f"xw{i}") for i in range(nr) ]
yh = [ model.NewIntVar(0,int(hr[i]),f"yh{i}") for i in range(nr) ]


# x2[i],y2[i] : upper limit of interval variable
x2 = [ model.NewIntVar(0,W,f"x2{i}") for i in range(nr) ]
y2 = [ model.NewIntVar(0,H,f"y2{i}") for i in range(nr) ]

# interval variables
xival = [ model.NewIntervalVar(x[i],xw[i],x2[i],f"xival{i}") for i in range(nr) ]
yival = [ model.NewIntervalVar(y[i],yh[i],y2[i],f"yival{i}") for i in range(nr) ]

#
# constraints
#
# The main idea here is: if an item is not selected, make its
# height and width zero.

# u[i] = 0  ==> xw[i]=yh[i]=0
# u[i] = 1  ==> xw[i]=hr[i],yh[i]=wr[i]
for i in range(nr):
  model.Add(xw[i]==wr[i]*u[i])
  model.Add(yh[i]==hr[i]*u[i])

# only one of non-rotated/rotated pair can be used
for i in range(n):
    model.Add(u[i]+u[i+n]<=1)

# no overlap.
model.AddNoOverlap2D(xival,yival)

# extra: this constraint helps performance enormously
model.Add(sum([wr[i]*hr[i]*u[i] for i in range(nr)])<=W*H)

# objective
model.Maximize(sum([u[i]*vr[i] for i in range(nr)]))


#
# solve model
#
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
# log does not work inside a Jupyter notebook
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
rc = solver.Solve(model)
print(f"return code:{rc}")
print(f"status:{solver.StatusName()}")
print()
print(solver.ResponseStats())
print()

#
# report solution
#
if rc == 4:
    used = {i for i in range(nr) if solver.Value(u[i]) == 1 }
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x'   : [solver.Value(x[i]) for i in used],
        'y'   : [solver.Value(y[i]) for i in used],
        'w'   : [wr[i] for i in used],
        'h'   : [hr[i] for i in used],
        'x2'  : [solver.Value(x2[i]) for i in used],
        'y2'  : [solver.Value(y2[i]) for i in used],
        'v'   : [vr[i] for i in used] })
    #print(df)

# Recreate the initial data table with the rotated items as well

df0 = pd.read_table(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')
df0 = pd.concat([df0, df0.rename(columns = {'width' : 'height', 'height' : 'width'})], ignore_index = True)
df0.drop_duplicates(subset = ['width', 'height'], inplace = True)

# Merge this into the solution, to have the item name, value and color

df = df.merge(df0, left_on = ['w','h'], right_on = ['width', 'height'], how = 'left')

# Drop v
df.drop(columns = ['v'], inplace = True)

# Display the complete solution

print(df)

# Print the total value

print(f'\nTotal area covered = {df["value"].sum()}')

Solution:
    x   y   w   h  x2  y2 item  width  height  available  value   color
0   0   0  24  18  24  18    L     24      18          2    432    blue
1  16  18  16  12  32  30    M     16      12          3    192  orange
2   0  18  16  12  16  30    M     16      12          3    192  orange
3  32  21  12   9  44  30    S     12       9          6    108   green
4  32  12  12   9  44  21    S     12       9          6    108   green
5  24   0   9  12  33  12    S      9      12          6    108   green
6  33   0   9  12  42  12    S      9      12          6    108   green

Total area covered = 1248

Plot:
# Draw the solution as colored rectangles

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

plt.figure(figsize = (W, H))
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = fig.gca()

for x, y, w, h, c in zip(df['x'], df['y'], df['w'], df['h'], df['color']) :
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x, y), w, h,
                edgecolor = 'black',
                facecolor = c,
                fill = True,
                lw = 5))

plt.xlim([0, W])
plt.ylim([0, H])
plt.show()



If this is a practical problem rather than just a mathematics problem you can probably find the optimal solution by playing around. You're just a quarter inch shy of $5\times 2$ of the smallest pieces.

A bit of both tbh. I am curious about the approach(es) one would use to resolve this, but I also need to cut the actual sheet. It's here on the table next to me :)

Nice question! It looks as though you're trying to minimise the waste, rather than maximise the number of tiles, is that right? In either case, it might be worth noting that you don't need the largest tile in your calculations, as you can make it with four of the smallest tiles: in any valid solution, this replacement would increase the tile count by $3$ and would not affect the area covered. From a purely area perspective, the best you could do would be to have two $20\times 15$ tiles and nine $15\times 11.25$, for a total area of $2118.75\text{cm}^2$, but I don't think this is achievable.

See http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/07/rectangles-no-overlap-constraints.html and http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/10/2d-knapsack-problem.html

@RobPratt : excellent, thanks a lot! I see that I was going to stumble on the continuous variables issue.

Is it 56x38 or 58x38?

@Lieven : oops sorry, went cross eyed, it is indeed 56 x 38. Roughly, because these are non-metric-system units. So yes the total area is 2128. I will correct the post.

I'll restate the problem as:

Fill as much of a 56 x 38 rectangle as possible with pieces of sizes 30 x 22.5, 20 x 15, and 15 x 11.25.

First, I'll divide all the dimensions by 1.25 to make the numbers easier:

Fill as much of a 44.8 x 30.4 rectangle as possible with pieces of sizes 24 x 18, 16 x 12, and 12 x 9.

The dimensions of the pieces are integers, so we might as well round down the dimensions of the original rectangle to integers too.

Fill as much of a 44 x 30 rectangle as possible with pieces of sizes 24 x 18, 16 x 12, and 12 x 9.

As Chris Lewis pointed out in the comments, the largest piece splits into four copies of the smallest piece, so we don't need to use the largest piece at all if we are just trying to maximise the area used.

Fill as much of a 44 x 30 rectangle as possible with pieces of sizes 16 x 12, and 12 x 9.

The area to fill is 1320, and the pieces have areas 192 and 108. Just looking at these area, we could use one of the following combinations of pieces:
$0*192+12*108=1296\\
1*192+10*108=1272\\
2*192+8*108=1248\\
3*192+6*108=1224\\
4*192+5*108=1308\\
5*192+3*108=1284\\
6*192+1*108=1260$
The third of these options, two of the larger and eight of the smaller pieces, is possible as shown here:

The four pieces in the top left could be combined to form a single larger piece. By the way, the gap in the middle is also a 4:3 rectangle.
The fourth option on the list (3L&6S) is also possible, but not as good. The other options have no solutions, so the above solution fills the largest proportion of the original area.
P.S. I verified this using my own Polysolver software.

Very nice, thank you! The solution proposed by @RobPratt, using the integer conversion you suggested, gives me the same coverage but a different set of sheets. I will post it now.
